# How to pass control values between userform events?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling with a userform (called Label_Select) that I created.
I'm initializing the userform with some text boxes and check boxes and assigning some values in them. 
Then I have a OK button on the userform that was created at design mode (I can create this button at runtime if that helps).

I need to use the text boxes and check boxes values in the code of the OK_Click, refer below.
Currently I get a "Sub or Function not defined" for the OK_Click sub.

How can I pass the text boxes and check boxes values between the userform initialize code and other click events of the userform?

Thank you for your responses

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim LotBox(500) As MSForms.TextBox
Dim SensorCheckBox(500) As MSForms.CheckBox

For i = 1 To 4
For j = 1 To 4

k = i + (4 * j)

Set LotBox(k - 4) = Label_Select.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
Set SensorCheckBox(k - 4) = Label_Select.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1")

With LotBox(k - 4)
 .Top = 250 + i * 25
 .Left = (j * 80) - 50
 .Width = 40
 .Height = 30
 .Font.Size = 14
 .Font.Name = "Calibri"
 .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken
 .Value = k
 .AutoSize = True
End With

With SensorCheckBox(k - 4)
    .Top = 246 + i * 25
    .Left = (j * 80) - 8
    .Height = 30
End With

If LotBox(k - 4).Value = " " Then
   Label_Select.Controls.Remove LotBox(k - 4).Name
   Label_Select.Controls.Remove SensorCheckBox(k - 4).Name
End If

Next j
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub OK_Click()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1)=LotBox(1).Value
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,1)=SensorCheckBox(1).Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making LotBox and SensorCheckBox public variables

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `LotBox` and `SensorCheckBox` within UserForm_Initialize, so as soon as that sub ends they will both go out of scope.

Move them up to the top of the module as Global variables.